# How to use Filters in firestore using javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I created a dashboard in which data came from firestore database where we have some requests coming from mobile to firestore and my job is to fetch that requests and display those requests in the form of HTML forms. but the problem is that multiple companies can login to the dashboard and every company has their own requests in firestore database now **my job is to show those requests according to CompanyName which is going to login**, I have a field in every request(document) by the name of CompanyName which shows that this request belongs from that company. **Then how should I use a filter through which I can filter requests according to the company name**.

For the rest, I did the whole fetching(without the filter I am talking about) and I also used the Login form where I have three inputs, email, password, and company name. nowhere is the company name now please help me how do I use the filter to filter requests(documents) according to that company name.

Please help if you can.
Thank you

> Now the code, where I need filter, is given below:

```
    function login() {
    var useremail    = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var CompanyName  = document.getElementById("CompanyName").value;
    var password     = document.getElementById("password").value;

const docRef = db.collection('Companies List')
   .where("CompanyEmail", "==", useremail)
   .where("CompanyPassword", "==", password);
// ^ separate .where()

docRef.get().then((snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.empty) {
    // no docs matched
    alert("Invalid Credentials")
  } else {
    console.log(snapshot.docs[0].data())
    Swal.fire({
      title:'Match!',
      text: 'Welcome to the dashboard',
      type: 'success',
    }).then(function() {
    
      
      //HERE I THINK I NEED A FILTER

      window.location = "home1.html";
    });
  }

});
}
```

[image: from here I am just checking if email and password match, login]

[image: And this sec image show the requests of all companies and I want to filter requests according to PoliclyCompany name]

Comment: Can you clearly list out the query requirements? email and password should be same, CompanyName === PolicyName. That's it from Companies List collection?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra where clause to the query:

```
const docRef = db.collection('Companies List')
   .where("CompanyEmail", "==", useremail)
   .where("CompanyPassword", "==", password)
   .where("CompanyName", "==", CompanyName); //  additinal where clause
```

Comment: When you execute the query with `docRef.get()` (just as you already did before) it will now also filter on `CompanyName`. If that is not happening for you, edit your question to show what you tried, the output you got, and the output you expected to get.

Comment: I used that filter but it can just only match CompanyName in the Companies List collection but I want when the data of CompanyName field is matched to the data of PolicyName field of Application list then fetch all those requests/Applications which have  CompanyName === PolicyName.